# Reading a 24/bit BMPs width/height

Tags: image, lua, bmp

I'm learning and trying to parse a BMP file, but how do I turn the width/height data into the correct number? I'm converting the bytes to decimal numbers but they come out in a weird format.

for instance, an image with a width of 3 comes out as 3 0 0 0, but a width of 400 comes out as 144 1 0 0

```
    local HexPaste = [[
    424d 480e 0000 0000 0000 3600 0000 2800
0000 9001 0000 0300 0000 0100 1800 0000
0000 120e 0000 120b 0000 120b 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 3333 3333 3333 3333 3333
3333 3333 3333 3333 3333
]] --took out a bunch of pixel data which doesn't matter yet

function Compress(Hex)
    local returnString = {}
    for s in string.gmatch(Hex,'%x') do
        table.insert(returnString,#returnString+1,s)
    end
    returnString = table.concat(returnString,'')
    return returnString
end

function Read(Hex,Type,ByteA,ByteB)
    local STable = {}
    for s = ByteA,ByteB do
        if Type == 'Text' then
            table.insert(STable,#STable+1,string.char(tonumber(string.sub(Hex,(s*2)-1,s*2),16)))
        elseif Type == 'Deci' then
            table.insert(STable,#STable+1,tonumber(string.sub(Hex,(s*2)-1,s*2),16))
        end
    end
    return table.concat(STable,'')
end

function ReadFile(Hex)
    Hex = Compress(Hex)
    if Read(Hex,'Text',1,2) == 'BM' then
        local Width = Read(Hex,'Deci',19,22)
        local Height = Read(Hex,'Deci',23,26)
        print('File is '..Width..'x'..Height)
    else
        error('Incorrect File Type')
    end
end

ReadFile(HexPaste)
```

Comment: Their both declared in the ReadFile function, bytes 19-22 and 23-26 (or 90 01 00 00 and 03 00 00 00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Compress(Hex)
   return (Hex:gsub('%X',''))
end

function Read(Hex,Type,ByteA,ByteB)
   Hex = Hex:sub(2*ByteA-1,2*ByteB)
   if Type == 'Text' then
      return (Hex:gsub('..',function(h)return h.char(tonumber(h,16))end))
   elseif Type == 'Deci' then
      local v = 0
      Hex:reverse():gsub('(.)(.)',function(b,a)v=v*256+tonumber(a..b,16)end)
      return v
   end
end
```